# How much editing can a non-technical user do on their Drupal site?

Tags: drupal

I know next to nothing about Drupal but I do have a question about it. Once a professional web developer builds a Drupal site for a customer, how much can a non-technical customer change?  Can they change all of the text?  Can then replace images.  Can they insert new images? Is there some kind of dashboard that gives them access to what they can change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is a content management system (CMS) and it's whole purpose is to make it easy for a non-technical user to use.  That includes creating, editing, and deleting of any content.  There is also a dashboard for them to go to and much more features such as setting user roles, permissions, a lot of modules (plugins), and the community is big so there is a lot of help if you need it.  The best way to start is to read the Drupal documentation and also follow some tutorials on youtube.

**Documentation**
[Drupal documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation)